# wordpress stylesheet not working

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am working on a new theme my stylesheet file name is style.css
this is the function that i am using in functions.php

```
    <?php

function add_stylesheet(){

        wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_stylesheet' );

?>
```

and My output is this

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

Stylesheet not working please help

Answer (score 0):

I think your handle may **not be** unique. Try using something like `wp_enqueue_style('lutrov-style', get_stylesheet_uri())` instead and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I changed butt still got this

Comment: <style type="text/css"></style>

Answer (score 0):

I just add this line to my header.php And its work `

`

This is my function in  functions.php